# Java version 11 not being picked up

Tags: java, installation, version

I am trying to run a piece of software on my Linux machine that demands that Java version 11 is installed.

When typing `java -version` to find out which current version of Java I have I get:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
```

To install version 11 I did (I am not sure this is right):

```
sudo yum install java-11-openjdk-devel
```

When I try to run the software the following message comes up:

```
Java version 11 is required.
Detected version 1.8.0_222
Please install the correct version.
```

And typing `java -version` returns the same message as initially.

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong and how I can get Java version 11 running?

Note: I am trying to do this remotely and so suggestions to download things from the web wouldn't help me!

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve by doing the following:

```
sudo alternatives --config java
```

and selecting the java version I wanted :)

Thanks for the help nonetheless!